# Export pandas dataframe to Excel with dynamic multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm trying to create an Excel file from a dataframe, where the Filename and Sheet Names are inside the data itself. There can be multiple Filenames and multiple Sheetnames per Filename. I have some code that uses two for loops, but wondering if there's a more efficient way than looping.

Example data:

[image: Example data]

```
#data is the initial dataframe
grouped = data.groupby("Filename")
for name, group in grouped:
    file_path = "{}".format(name)
    if "xlsx" in file_path or "csv" in file_path:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl')       
        df = group.drop('Filename',1)
        grouped = df.groupby('Sheetname')
        for name, group in grouped:
            df = group.drop('Sheetname',1)
            if "xlsx" in file_path:
                df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name=name)
            elif "csv" in file_path:
                df.to_csv(writer,index=False)
            else:
                print("Filename is not valid.")
                break
        writer.save()
    else:
        print("Filename is not valid.")
        break
```